# Android : Network on main Thread with a Widget

Tags: android, multithreading, exception, networking, widget

I made a simple widget (`AppWidgetProvider`). To load its content, it needs to connect to the internet (`JSoup` is amazing). Obviously, I've got a wonderful `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. I tried to do an `AsyncTask` but Eclipse is shouting `No enclosing instance of type WidgetClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type WidgetClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of WidgetClass).` at me, so I can't run it.

How could I solve it ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is the *specific* error message you're getting? Also the line that Eclipse complains about. Also consider using proper Java naming conventions Class names start with Capitals; variable names don't.

Comment: Eclipse would definitely not want something like `myAsync a = new myAsync().execute()` since new myAsync.execute() might not return an instance of myAsync unless you programmed it. I believe you misunderstood something. Would you mind putting up your code.

Comment: When I try `new Background().execute("");` i've got `No enclosing instance of type Widget is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Widget (e.g. x.new A() where x 
 is an instance of Widget).`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are trying to call myAsync().execute() in declaration area?

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    new myAsync().execute();//wouldn't work
}
```

Comment: Nope, it's in the onUpdate method.

Comment: I did it : When I try new Background().execute(""); i've got No enclosing instance of type WidgetClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type WidgetClass (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of WidgetClass). (my class is called WidgetClass)